# What does this piece of C code do ? [confusing with function body code]

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

```
void my_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
   (*dest)? my_strcat(++dest, src): (*dest++ = *src++)? my_strcat(dest, src): 0 ;
}

/* driver function to test above function */
int main()
{
    char dest[100] = "geeksfor";
    char *src = "geeks";
    my_strcat(dest, src);
    printf(" %s ", dest);
    getchar();
}
```

I understand C topics pointers and ternary operator very well but confusing with above code **i.e.** what is this trying to check in conditional statement and further what is happening in true and false dependent statements.

Can anyone explain it in detail what this code actually doing ?

Comment: This function relies on the `dest` being fully zeroed prior to the call

Comment: And now that geeksforgeeks has taught you how to write bad C code, find a tutorial that teaches the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It assumes that the destination buffer, `char dest[100]`, is not only null-terminated, but filled with `\0` all through to the end.

So first, `*dest` is checking whether the character where `dest` points to, is a null-terminator, *i.e.* `0`.

If it has not found it, then it recursively calls itself, but one position to the right, eventually finding the null-terminator. (If there is no null-terminator, then this function is dangerous, writing past the buffer.)

If it *does* find the null-terminator, then it copies one character from the source to the destination, then calls itself with both pointers moved to the right, continuing the copy. (Again, this seems to be done without proper checking of bounds.)

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator `?` is just an if-else, so the body is equivalent to:

```
if(*dest)
    my_strcat(++dest, src);
else
    if(*dest++ = *src++)
        my_strcat(dest, src);
    else
        0;
```

So it will the function recursively, while assuming that `dest` is a NULL-terminated string, with `\0` till its end though, that's why it test `*dest`. Furthermore, I think you know what this function does now.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
(*dest)? my_strcat(++dest, src): (*dest++ = *src++)? my_strcat(dest, src): 0 ;
```

is very recursive.

steps through the 'dest' until a '\0' char is found, then copys a char from 'src' to 'dest'  and if the copied char is NOT a '\0' then calls itself again (and again and again) until all the characters, including the final '\0' are copied.

However, I would worry about that final zero, as that is not an executable statement.  Suggest using `return` instead

Comment: No need to worry about final `0`. Expressions are legitimate statements.

Answer (score 0):

The function copies the string given as `src` into the `\0` filled positions given in `dest` array.  So, supposing you have

```
char dest[100] = "geeks for\0 foo \0\0\0 bar ";
char *src = "geeks";
```

the result will be

```
geeks forg foo eek bar s
         ^     ^^^     ^ <-- geeks (src)
^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^   ^^^^^  <-- geeks for\0 foo \0 bar \0\0\0... (dest)
```